# In Jenkins, can I trigger a downstream job once a day

Tags: jenkins

We've got a Jenkins setup where we do incremental builds on SCM change, validate and then if this works do a full build (from scratch). This basically works but we waste time doing full builds during the day that we don't normally use.

I know we could trigger full builds every night, but many of our branches won't change for a few days - and then we might get a rush of changes. Thus building every branch every night is wasteful too.

What I really want is some mechanism where we only do the full builds once (say at night) if there has been an SCM change and the incremental build and validate worked - there is no point auto-triggering full builds where the incremental build and validate failed. Actually just "the incremental build and validate worked" should suffice - as these normally just run on SCM change.

Any suggestions? Is there some Jenkins extension that would help with this?

Comment: Hi @johnfo,
I am looking for the same trigger mechanism, did you solve you issue?

Answer (score -1):

To achieve what you've asked for you can create a new job that is the same as your existing one, but have it only poll the SCM once a day, for a nightly build.
Set the schedule to something like this: `H H(0-5) * * *`.

In your original job, remove the post-build triggering of a full build.

That will give you pretty much what you've asked for, except the nightly build will do an incremental build and then a full build if the incremental one succeeded, rather than just checking the result of the last incremental build.

**BUT...**

What is the cost of the 'waste' you are trying to avoid? How much does running a full build every night actually cost you? And wouldn't you be better off finding out when the full build is broken as soon as possible, i.e. during the day when it was broken rather than only the following morning?